# Non Linear Differential Equation: Switching Exponentiation with Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

For which functions $y(x)$ can one swap the order of their derivative with their exponent?

$$\left(\frac{d^my}{dx^m}\right)^n\overset{!}{=}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\left(y^n\right), \quad\quad m,n\in\mathbb{N}^*$$

Of course there are some trivial solutions with constant functions or with $n=1$.

I also found the general solution for $m=1$:

$$\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)^n\overset{!}{=}\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(y^n\bigg) = n \frac{dy}{dx}y^{n-1}$$

$$\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)^{n-1}=ny^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= n^{\frac{1}{n-1}}y \quad\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad\quad y = Ce^{x n^\frac{1}{n-1}} $$

But I'm already stuck with $m=2$:

$$\bigg(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\bigg)^n\overset{!}{=}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\bigg(y^n\bigg) = n \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(y^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg) = n\bigg((n-1)y^{n-2}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)^2+y^{n-1}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\bigg)$$

Is there a way to find a general solution for the triples $y$, $m$ and $n$. Or even just a few other non trivial solutions?

Comment: Linear functions work for $m>n>=1$

Comment: A general solution looks at best difficult even for $n = 2, m = 2$, but n.b. for $n > 1$, $y(x) = C \exp \left(n^\frac{1}{n - 1} x\right)$ is a solution for all $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a solution for $m=2$. Taking the transformations $y'_x=yp(\xi)$ and $\xi=\log(y)$ yields the autonomous first order equation
\begin{align}\tag{1}
p^{n-1}(p+p'_\xi)^n=n(np+p'_\xi).
\end{align}
I cannot find a point transformation or contact transformation which yields a nice equation for arbitrary $n$, so it seems we are stuck with solving the $n$th order polynomial for $p'_\xi$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}p^{n-k}(p'_\xi)^n-np^{1-n}p'_\xi=n^2p^{2-n}.\tag{2}
\end{align}

For the cases where you can where you can solve for $p'_\xi$ (for $n<5$ you can always, of course) we would have
\begin{align}
p'_\xi=f(p)\quad\implies\quad y=C\exp\int\frac{\mathrm dp}{f(p)}.
\end{align}
Where I've used $y=\exp(\xi)$. In the case of $n=2$ we have that
\begin{align}
y=C\left(3\mp\sqrt{2p^2+1}\right)^{-3/4}\left(\pm\sqrt{2p^2+1}+1\right)^{-1/4}
\end{align}
Surprisingly, [Wolfram Alpha is able to analytically solve for $p$ in the $n=2$ case](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20y%283-sqrt%282x%5E2%2B1%29%29%5E%283%2F4%29%28sqrt%282x%5E2%2B1%29%2B1%29%5E%281%2F4%29%3DC%20for%20x). So you could then directly separate and integrate for a solution. For the general case we will instead seek a parametric solution.

Note that $p=y'_x/y$, so if we take $y=\exp(u)$ we have
\begin{align}
u=\left(\int \frac{\mathrm d u'_x}{f(u'_x)}\right)^C.
\end{align}
Equations of the form $u=g(u'_x)$ have the parametric solution $u=g(\tau)$, $x=\smallint g'(\tau)/\tau \mathrm d\tau +C_0$, so then our general parametric solution for $m=2$ is
\begin{align}
y=C\exp\int \frac{\mathrm d \tau}{f(\tau)},\quad x=C\int \frac{1}{\tau f(\tau)}\left(\int \frac{\mathrm d \tau}{f(\tau)}\right)^{C-1}\mathrm d\tau+C_0,
\end{align}
where $f(p)$ is the solution to the polynomial in (1).

Additionally, this solution reduces to the particular solution given by @TravisWillse for $f(\tau)=(C-1)(Cn^{1/(n-1)})^{1/(C-1)}\tau^{(C-2)/(C-1)}$.

---

The previous tricks do not yield a solution for the case $m=3$. Let us take the same transformations, giving
\begin{align}
&y'_x=yp,\quad y''_{xx}=yp(p+p'_\xi),\quad y'''_{xxx}=y(p^2p''_{\xi\xi}+p(p'_\xi)^2+3p^2p'_\xi+p^3),\\
&(y^n)'_x=ny^np,\quad (y^n)''_{xx}=y^n(npp'_\xi+n^2p^2),\\&(y^n)'''_{xxx}=y^n(np^2p''_{\xi\xi}+np(p'_\xi)^2+3n^2p^2p'_\xi+n^3p^3).
\end{align}
And so $(y'''_{xxx})^n=(y^n)'''_{xxx}$ becomes
\begin{align}
(p^2p''_{\xi\xi}+p(p'_\xi)^2+3p^2p'_\xi+p^3)^n=np^2p''_{\xi\xi}+np(p'_\xi)^2+3n^2p^2p'_\xi+n^3p^3.
\end{align}
If we take $p'_\xi=pz(\eta)$ and $\eta=\log(p)$ we then have
\begin{align}
p'_\xi=pz(\eta),\quad p''_{\xi\xi}=pz(z+z'_\eta)
\end{align}
and so
\begin{align}
(zz'_\eta+2z^2+3z+1)^n=ne^{3(1-n)\eta}(zz'_\eta+(1+n)z^2+3nz+n^2),
\end{align}
which I doubt there is a solution here except for $n=1$.